# jQuery: How do I insert an html string an arbitrary number of times (i.e. not with an each() function)?

Tags: jquery

I just need to take a certain html query object and append it to an html element a lot of times. I have this:

```
var box = $("<div class='box'>&nbsp</div>");
$("#firstbox").after(box);
```

and it works fine, but it just adds one 'box' after the #firstbox element. I'd like to do something like this:

```
var box = $("<div class='box'>&nbsp</div>");
$("#firstbox").after(box * 6000);
```

so that it will insert 6000 copies of that 'box' html, but this is not working. This is I'm sure the easiest thing to do, but I can't seem to find how to multiply actions like this without using the each() function, which doesn't apply here because I don't have 6000 of anything on my page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a for loop:

```
for(var i=0;i<6000;i++) {
    $("#firstbox").after("<div class='box'>b</div>");
}
```

Comment: For simplicity, sure, but in actual code, you should probably have the  $("#firstbox") outside the loop to avoid a lookup for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This is just basic JavaScript:

```
function duplicate(str, num) {
  temp = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    temp += str;
  }

  return temp;
}
```

Use it like so:

```
$("#firstbox").after(duplicate(box.html(), 6000));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is available in python, so I can understand the confusion, but this operation always involves a for loop or .each, etc in javascript because the * operator cannot be overloaded in the language.